# Resize image on client side before uploading to the server

Tags: javascript, php, image, image-resizing

There is plenty of information on the web about resizing an uploaded image on the server. I can't find any information about resizing it on the client instead.

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30557954/4842333) PHP code to handle the upload. It works, but my web server only accepts uploads of 2 MB or smaller. Therefore, I want the client side code to resize the uploaded image to be no larger than this.

Comment: For what it's worth, I disagree with the close votes, though the question should be reworded to remove the mentions of PHP. Chances are there might be a duplicate somewhere though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. PHP is a server side language. You cannot resize images on client side with PHP.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible with .js?

Comment: With the new JS File API a number of file manipulations can be done on local files, but that doesn't include image resizing to my knowledge. Your best bet is to execute a batch resize of all your images (independently from your application) prior to uploading the files.

Comment: mm ok, How can I execute a batch resize? (sorry I'm not very familiar with)

Comment: There are several image manipulation applications. I'm not too familiar with them, but I know for e.g. that you can create a batch resize action in Photoshop.

Comment: Also, there's `imagemagick`. This is a command line tool and you could write a script that processes all your images and uses imagamagick to resize them.

Comment: But I'll be not the only one that will add images, I need something very simple that resize the images automatically when someone loads a pic. and it has to work with any kind of computer so also in computers without photoshop. Is it possible?

Comment: Consider upgrading your server and doing the image resize there centrally instead of individually on each of your users' computer.

Comment: ok, So it's impossible without upgrade (I'm not in charge to decide which server to use..)

Comment: Relevant question about JS resize before upload: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333971/html5-pre-resize-images-before-uploading